# Where should persistent data be saved in an Angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm building an app that requires access to a data set that is fetched by the page that bootstraps the application and saved as a JSON object in a javascript variable in that page... which I obviously have access to from within the app.

The data is used throughout the app for various functionality. Additionally, some of that data is changed an/or new data is added.

Everything I've read states that persistent data like that should be saved in a service or factory, since they are singletons and they can be easily injected into any controller that needs access to it. So I wrote a service with some getter/setter methods that will allow me to grab or change data stored within it.

I'm just wondering what the difference is between storing the data in a service, where I'd do something like this to access it:

```
$scope.userAddr1 = PersistentData.get('profileData', 'userAddr1');
```

and continuing to store it in the native JavaScript of the parent/bootstrapping page where I'd do something like this to access it:

```
$scope.userAddr1 = profileData.userAddr1;
```

I can see how storing it in the service would help keep things organized, but are there any other reasons why this is considered to be best practice?

Comment: I can't tell what you mean by "parent/bootstrapping page". If you mean some specific controller, then the data isn't storied at all. When the controller is unloaded, the data will be gone. If you mean some global controller that is always present, that is bad practice because it is global state. Either way, controllers are meant to be light and just wire up the UI to services. The controller isn't the destination for that data, it just tells the UI and services how/where to send and receive data.

Comment: By "parent/bootstrapping page" I meant the HTML (or in this case the .jsp) page in which the Angular app is embedded... the page containing `data-ng-app="someAppName"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're clients are using modern browsers, then you can use [Web storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage) (localStorage or sessionStorage).